# Crate join queries takes too much time

Tags: java, database, caching, memcached, cratedb

Pre Requirement : I need to find all the matching result in one query which is more than 40K results.

Requirement : Two tables - product and product_category. I am trying to fetch all the products with matching category from product_category table.

Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE catalog.product (
    product_id string PRIMARY KEY index using plain,
    name string,
    sku string,
) clustered by (product_id) into 4 shards;

create table catalog.product_category (
    category_id string primary key index using plain,
    product_id  string primary key index using plain,
    INDEX product_category_index using plain(product_id, category_id)
    active boolean,
    parent_category_id integer,
    updated_at timestamp
);
```

Join Query :

```
select p.product_id from catalog.product_category pc join catalog.product p on p.product_id=pc.product_id limit 40000;
```

Tried multiple things - indexing product_id (both as integer and string) etc.

Result : To showup 35K result it is taking more than 90 seconds everytime.

Problem : What can I do to optimize the query response time?

Some Other Information :
 - CPU Core  -4
 - Tried with one or multiple nodes
 - Default Sharding
 - Total number of products - 35K and product_category has 35K enteries only.

Usecase : I am trying to use crateDB as persistent cache but with the given query response time we can't really do that. So we will move to some in-memory database like REDIS or Memcache. The reason to choose crateDB was the querying ability on your persistent data.

Comment: Seems some other problem than your engine and query.

Comment: Copy the query and check directly querying in your db. (E.g., we check in PHPMYADMIN)

Comment: Could you try reversing your table join ? "product" first and then "product_category"

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu I downlaoded latest Crate1.0.3 and using Crash.bat to query. Please suggest how can I improve on it.

Comment: @GauravJ Tried reversing the join, still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Joining on `STRING` type columns is very expensive comparing to joining on `NUMERIC` types (equality check on string values is much more expensive than on numeric values). If you don't have a special reason for doing that I'd recommend to change them to a `NUMERIC` type (e.g. `INTEGER`, `LONG`, ...), this would improve the query speed by a multiple factor.

Btw. `index using plain` is the default index setting for all columns, so you could just leave it out.
Also the compound index `product_category_index` will not help improving the join query, it's just important if you would filter on that by using a `WHERE` clause including this index column.

*Updated*

Another improvement you can do is adding an `ORDER BY p.product_id, pc.product_id` clause. By this, the join algorithm could stop when it reached your applied `LIMIT`.

Comment: @SanjayKumar Updated my answer with an `ORDER BY` suggestion.

Comment: I tried what you said, the only way the performance got blazingly fast was when I put everything in a single table. Though it is slower than in memory access but comparable.  Thanks @Sabastian.